# Unable to read from filedescriptor, program is killed

Tags: c++, linux, iostream, file-descriptor

I am trying to read a filedescriptor with read() but my program freezes there and after a while is `Killed`. Is there a timeout for reading filedescriptors or a good way to check why this happens? 
My program uses gadgetfs to read/write from/to USB in user space.
Thanks!
This is the code. It's a modified version of the usb.c samle (http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/usb.c)

```
struct pollfd ep0_poll;
ep0_poll.fd = gadgetFS_FD;
ep0_poll.events = POLLIN | POLLOUT | POLLHUP;

while(){
                int nPoll = poll(&ep0_poll, 1, 250);    
            if(nPoll == 0)
                continue;

            if (nPoll < 0) {
                printf("poll failed");          
            }

            usb_gadgetfs_event  aoEvent [5];
            ssize_t nRead = read (ep0_poll.fd, &aoEvent, sizeof aoEvent);

            if (nRead < 0) {
                if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                    sleep (1);
                    continue;
                }
                printf("ep0 read after poll");
            }

                  ...

    }
```

Comment: Do *you* kill it, or is it killed by some other program? How do you read from the descriptor? Where's the code?

Comment: Its killed by Linux, not by me, after a while.

Comment: You don't actually *check* if the descriptor is ready to be read, you just assume it is. What if the `poll` function timeouts? You need to either check if the `poll` function timeouts, or if `POLLIN` is set in `ep0_poll.revents`, preferably both.